# PHP Ordem aletória

Tags: php, xml

Tenho um código PHP que puxa um XML e joga na tela porém eu gostaria que ele rodasse em ordem aleatória e não a ordem que está no XML.

Isso é possível?

Código que estou usando.

### PHP

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('produtos.xml');
foreach ($xml as $oferta){
$a = "<div class='produto'><a href=" . $oferta->links->link["url"]. ">". $oferta->offerName. "</a><br>";
$a .= "" . $oferta->offerShortName. "<br>";
$a .= "<img src=" . $oferta->thumbnail["url"]. " width='80%;'><br>";
$a .= "R$" . $oferta->price->value.  "<br>";
$a .= "<a href=" . $oferta->links->link["url"]. ">comprar</a><br>"; 
$a .= "<a href=" . $oferta->links->link["url"]. "><img src=" . $oferta->seller->thumbnail["url"]. "></a><br></div>";
echo $a;
```

### XML

```
<offer categoryId="5" id="149417086" productId="599409">
    <offerName>DVD Portátil Tectoy Bob Esponja DVT - P4000 ( 117700377 )</offerName>
    <offerShortName>Dvd Portátil </offerShortName>
    <links>
        <link url="http://links.lomadee.com/ls/of/Y249Z1F3RjttZHNyYz0zMzU4MzI4NTtlbXBfaWQ9ODE7bWRhcHA9NTc5ODtwcm9kX2lkPTE0OTQxNzA4Njt4bGs9aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hbWVyaWNhbmFzLmNvbS5ici9wcm9kdXRvLzExNzcwMDM3Ny9kdmQtcG9ydGF0aWwtdGVjdG95LWJvYi1lc3BvbmphLWR2dC1wNDAwMD87Y291bnRyeT1CUjtodD02YzRlZTg1ZjcyNjhmYzVjODdmOWE3NTJjZDZhNDE2NDttZGR0bj0w.html" type="offer"/>
    </links>
    <thumbnail url="http://iacom.s8.com.br/produtos/01/00/item/117700/3/117700377_1GG.jpg"/>
    <price>
        <currency abbreviation="BRL"/>
        <value>296.88</value>
    </price>
    <seller id="81" isTrustedStore="true" pagamentoDigital="false" advertiserId="0" oneClickBuy="false" oneClickBuyValue="0" cpcDifferentiated="false">
        <sellerName>Americanas.com</sellerName>
        <thumbnail url="http://imagem.buscape.com.br/vitrine/logo81.gif"/>
        <links>
            <link url="http://www.americanas.com.br" type="seller"/>
        </links>
        <contacts>
            <contact value="4003-4848" label="Atendimento"/>
            <contact value="0300-7893200" label="Televendas"/>
            <contact value="4003-1000" label="Televendas"/>
        </contacts>
        <rating>
            <userAverageRating>
                <numComments>10773</numComments>
                <rating>0.0</rating>
            </userAverageRating>
            <eBitRating>
                <numComments>10773</numComments>
                <rating>Diamante</rating>
                <ratingNew>e-bit Excelente</ratingNew>
                <ratingId>40</ratingId>
                <ebitId>568</ebitId>
            </eBitRating>
        </rating>
    </seller>
</offer>
<offer categoryId="10" id="120912411">
    <offerName>Caixa de Som Portátil Azul SSMN 101 - HoMedics ( 110969373 )</offerName>
    <offerShortName>Caixa De Som </offerShortName>
    <links>
        <link url="http://links.lomadee.com/ls/of/Y249N01WSTttZHNyYz0zMzU4MzI4NTtlbXBfaWQ9ODE7bWRhcHA9NTc5ODtwcm9kX2lkPTEyMDkxMjQxMTt4bGs9aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hbWVyaWNhbmFzLmNvbS5ici9wcm9kdXRvLzExMDk2OTM3My9jYWl4YS1kZS1zb20tcG9ydGF0aWwtYXp1bC1zc21uLTEwMS1ob21lZGljcz9lcGFyPWJ1c2NhcGUmb3BuPVlZTktaQjtjb3VudHJ5PUJSO2h0PWQ1YzNlYzRkNjY2MTgzZTA1NmVlMzdhYmJmZDA4Mzc2O21kZHRuPTA-.html" type="offer"/>
    </links>
    <thumbnail url="http://thumbs.buscape.com.br/T100x100/__2.81-734fa1b.jpg"/>
    <price>
        <currency abbreviation="BRL"/>
        <value>44.91</value>
    </price>
    <seller id="81" isTrustedStore="true" pagamentoDigital="false" advertiserId="0" oneClickBuy="false" oneClickBuyValue="0" cpcDifferentiated="false">
        <sellerName>Americanas.com</sellerName>
        <thumbnail url="http://imagem.buscape.com.br/vitrine/logo81.gif"/>
        <links>
            <link url="http://www.americanas.com.br" type="seller"/>
        </links>
        <contacts>
            <contact value="4003-4848" label="Atendimento"/>
            <contact value="0300-7893200" label="Televendas"/>
            <contact value="4003-1000" label="Televendas"/>
        </contacts>
        <rating>
            <userAverageRating>
                <numComments>10773</numComments>
                <rating>0.0</rating>
            </userAverageRating>
            <eBitRating>
                <numComments>10773</numComments>
                <rating>Diamante</rating>
                <ratingNew>e-bit Excelente</ratingNew>
                <ratingId>40</ratingId>
                <ebitId>568</ebitId>
            </eBitRating>
        </rating>
    </seller>
</offer>
```

Comment: Como assim rodar em ordem aleatória?

Comment: `shuffle($xml->links)` antes do `for`.

Comment: Mas nisso ele vai randomizar apenas o link e não a div inteira, correto?
E não entendi como aplica.

Comment: desculpe...
Então esse bloco inteiro gera uma div com um produto dentro, nome, imagem, link, etc...
É como se fosse uma loja virtual, isso é um produto e no xml existem muitos outros e quero que estes produtos fiquem em ordem randômica e não use apenas a sequencia que está no xml.

Deu pra entender ou ainda fui muito confuso?

Comment: Deu pra entender sim. E isso que te falei você testou ?

Comment: Fiz mas a única coisa que ele fez foi deixar os links aleatórios, preciso que o conteúdo dentro da div seja do mesmo produto.

Vou adicionar lá em cima o XML com apenas 2 produtos.

Comment: Ótimo. Adiciona aí para vermos do que se trata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use um count para contar a quantidade de arrays que contém a variável $xml, use esse numero para montar um for e montar um outro array com números aleatórios com limite de quantidade de arrays no seus $xml, monte desse jeito:

```
$qtd_array = count($xml->offer) - 1;    
for($i= 0; $i<= $qtd_array; $i++){
    $num_alea = rand(0, $qtd_array);
    if($i >= 1){
        while(in_array($num_alea, $num_aleatorio)){
             $num_alea = rand(0, $qtd_array);
        }
    }
$num_aleatorio[$i] = $num_alea;

$a = "<div class='produto'><a href=" . $xml->offer[$num_aleatorio[$i]]->links->link["url"]. ">". 
$xml->offer[$num_aleatorio[$i]]->offerName. "</a><br>";
$a .= "" . $xml->offer[$num_aleatorio[$i]]->offerShortName. "<br>";
$a .= "<img src=" . $xml->offer[$num_aleatorio[$i]]->thumbnail["url"]. " width='80%;'><br>";
$a .= "R$" . $xml->offer[$num_aleatorio[$i]]->price->value.  "<br>";
$a .= "<a href=" .$xml->offer[$num_aleatorio[$i]]->links->link["url"]. ">comprar</a><br>"; 
$a .= "<a href=" .$xml->offer[$num_aleatorio[$i]]->links->link["url"]. "><img src=" . $xml->offer[$num_aleatorio[$i]]->seller->thumbnail["url"]. "></a><br></div>";
echo $a;
```

Tente isso Caso não de certo, só retornar aqui ;)

Comment: Deu este erro em todos os produtos.

Warning: main(): Cannot add element oferta number 3 when only 0 such elements exist in

Comment: Ele mostra a linha?

Comment: Não, só aparece isso repetindo por por diversas vezes, só alterando o number 3 por outro número.

Comment: Faz o seguinte, todo XML precisa ter uma raiz, mudei a resposta, ve acima. vamos supor que seu xml tem uma rais <produtos></produtos>

Comment: Funcionou agora.

Por algum motivo o style ficou meio estranho mas isso da para arrumar.

Obrigado!

Comment: Ai já fica com você rs.

Answer (score 0):

`shuffle($xml->offer)` antes do `for`.

Essa função vai randomizar o objeto `offer`dentro do `XML`.

Veja se funciona assim.

Comment: Não funcionou nem como mostrou nem assim.
 shuffle ($oferta->offer);
 foreach ($xml  as $oferta ){